# I am trying to excute java from solaris, getting invalid argument error

Tags: java, solaris

I am giving command like this
bash-3.00$/app/jdk1.6.0_11/bin/java -version , it is giving error like
bash-3.00: /app/jdk1.6.0_11/bin/java: invalid argument

Comment: What do you get if you run: bash-3.00$/app/jdk1.6.0_11/bin/java (i.e. without -version) ?

Answer (score 10):

"Invalid argument" is the error you get on Solaris when you try running a SPARC binary on an x86 platform.   Make sure the java runtime you have installed in /app is the right version for your hardware - you can use the `file` command to check, for example:

```
% file /net/pkg/export/pkg.sparc.sunos5/gnu/bin/ls
/net/pkg/export/pkg.sparc.sunos5/gnu/bin/ls:    ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped

% file /net/pkg/export/pkg.i386.sunos5/gnu/bin/tar
/net/pkg/export/pkg.i386.sunos5/gnu/bin/tar:    ELF 32-bit LSB executable 80386 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped
```

Comment: or vice versa, running x86/64 java on a Solaris sparc machine

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bash-3.00$ source /app/jdk1.6.0_11/bin/java -version
```

or

```
bash-3.00$ . /app/jdk1.6.0_11/bin/java -version
```

([Bash manual](http://ss64.com/bash/period.html))

I suggest you adding Java JDK path to your Bash PATH environment variable, so you don't have to write the whole path.

Comment: What is the out of the command: file /app/jdk1.6.0_11/bin/java

Comment: What's the ouput of `ls /app/jdk1.6.0_11/bin/java` ?

Comment: bash-3.00$ source /app/jdk1.6.0_11/bin/java -version & bash-3.00$ . /app/jdk1.6.0_11/bin/java -version out put is ELF command not found

Comment: Execute jim mcnamara's command or mine and tell us the output.