# running an executable c++ program in solaris

Tags: c++, solaris

I compiled my class `Transfer` correctly in `Solaris`. There is the executable file `transfer`. If i were in `Linux`, I would to `./transfer` and the program would execute perfectly. However, when I run `./transfer` in `Solaris` I get:

```
bash: ./transfer: invalid argument
```

Does someone know how to run an executable in `Solaris`?

Comment: It should not be significantly different for something like this.  How *exactly* do you run your program...do you include any arguments after `./transfer`?  Also, please run `file ./transfer` to see what kind of file it is (presumably it has to be a binary of the architecture that matches your machine).

Comment: If it doesn't execute with `./transfer`, then you *didn't* compile it correctly.  Show us the command line you used to compile it.

Comment: @KeithFlower Could you make comment an answer? YOU DESERVE +15

Comment: Thanks...the cross-compilation thing bit me once on Solaris, too..."invalid argument" is vague enough, eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like compilation was done targeting a different architecture than the host machine.

See related thread -  [x86 binary on a SPARC machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36376/what-does-invalid-argument-mean-in-solaris).

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the follwing pages that I append here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36376/what-does-invalid-argument-mean-in-solaris

[I am trying to excute java from solaris, getting invalid argument error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428280/i-am-trying-to-excute-java-from-solaris-getting-invalid-argument-error)

and also consider correct folder of files and file permissions, sometimes these issues can make problems.