# My python scripts in virtualenv fail with error "bad interpreter: Invalid argument"

Tags: python, virtualenv, parallels

**[UPDATE] This seems to be a problem with the Parallels VM (https://forum.parallels.com/threads/execution-files-located-on-shared-folders-mount-with-exec.352815/). Thanks to all who commented!**

I have a strange problem with my virtualenv (on Ubuntu 20.04). I activate my virtualenv as follows.

```
aravind@vetinari:test_venv$ rm -r venv
aravind@vetinari:test_venv$ python -m venv venv
aravind@vetinari:test_venv$ source venv/bin/activate
```

I then install an empty package with one script called `test_version.py` which is also successful.

```
(venv) aravind@vetinari:test_venv$ python -m pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv
Installing collected packages: test-venv
  Attempting uninstall: test-venv
    Found existing installation: test-venv 0.0.1.dev0
    Not uninstalling test-venv at /media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv, outside environment /media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv/venv
    Can't uninstall 'test-venv'. No files were found to uninstall.
  Running setup.py develop for test-venv
Successfully installed test-venv
```

When I run it with the virtualenv python, it runs fine.

```
(venv) aravind@vetinari:test_venv$ /media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv/venv/bin/python /media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv/venv/bin/test_version.py 
3.8.10
```

However, when I run it as a standalone script, I get this error.

```
(venv) aravind@vetinari:test_venv$ /media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv/venv/bin/test_version.py 
bash: /media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv/venv/bin/test_version.py: /media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv/venv/bin/python: bad interpreter: Invalid argument
```

Here are the contents of the installed script.

```
(venv) aravind@vetinari:test_venv$ cat /media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv/venv/bin/test_version.py 
#!/media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv/venv/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-DEV-SCRIPT: 'test-venv==0.0.1.dev0','test_version.py'
__requires__ = 'test-venv==0.0.1.dev0'
__import__('pkg_resources').require('test-venv==0.0.1.dev0')
__file__ = '/media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv/bin/test_version.py'
with open(__file__) as f:
    exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))
```

Note that the shebang interpreter (media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv/venv/bin/python) in the script is present and it works fine when I execute it with that python but not when I run it as a standalone script.

Here are the contents of the script.

```
(venv) aravind@vetinari:test_venv$ cat bin/test_version.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import platform; print(platform.python_version())
```

and the `setup.py`.

```
(venv) aravind@vetinari:test_venv$ cat setup.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='test_venv',
      version='0.0.1dev',
      description='Test',
      author='Aravind Sundaresan',
      maintainer='Aravind Sundaresan',
      packages=find_packages(),
      scripts=["bin/test_version.py",],
      install_requires=[],
      zip_safe=False
      )
```

Comment: Please provide `setup.py` and other relevant files to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `#!/media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv/venv/bin/python` Does that program exist?

Comment: @PeterBadida I have updated the question with the information you requested. Is there an easy way to provide the package?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, that program exists. In fact `/media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv/venv/bin/python /media/psf/Home/projects/test_venv/venv/bin/test_version.py` works fine.

Comment: Any chance you might have gotten DOS newlines into your file somehow? If it contains `CR`s instead of `CRLF`s, that would make this less surprising.

Comment: If not, my next step would be to pull out `strace` and watch for the actual syscall that fails.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think you may be onto something. This is in an Ubuntu VM running on OS X and on the shared folder. It used to work fine before, I'm not sure what changed but is it possible that the problem could be caused by the virtualenv being on a folder shared with the host OS (macos).

Comment: A venv is platform-specific. You can't use a MacOS one on Ubuntu, nor the inverse.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not using a MacOS venv on Ubuntu. All the operations are on Ubuntu.

Comment: [UPDATE] This seems to be a different problem from what I posted and not relevant to virtualenv as such. It is that on a folder shared with the host, I'm unable to run scripts as executables. I'm not sure whether to edit this question or post a new one.

Comment: @AravindSundaresan I added the `parallels` tag for you. Re the running, you're facing a rather nasty issue. Consider creating a new question just for Parallels I guess or simply switch to a different emulator for the quickest fix. Maybe there's even a simple converter somewhere online and if not, check the `history` command for your VM, copy-paste files to host and reinstall in a different emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, after [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352652/my-python-scripts-in-virtualenv-fail-with-error-bad-interpreter-invalid-argume#comment122580447_69352652) I see you're sharing a folder. Virtual environment is OS-specific, therefore it's a different executable (similar like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436882/5994041)).

MacOS venv works only on MacOS. Linux venv works only on Linux. Create venv from scratch in that VM.

`file <path to python>` should show the executables differ, thus bash can't execute it because it can't be executed on Linux (not an ELF binary).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Peter. I want to clarify that while the folder is shared from the host (Mac) the virtualenv was created on Linux as you suggested. I was not trying to share a virtualenv across OSes. This error happens when the virtualenv is on a shared folder so it definitely seems to be related to that. However, I'm still trying to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: @AravindSundaresan never heard of Parallels, but I'm glad you found the problem. Perhaps try to utilize a different emulator such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMWare player](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player.html) or even switch to [Docker](https://docker.com) for a lightweight usage of the platform (works on MacOS and Windows too).